# Placeholder and view only values in Django model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

this has been asked a few times, but the answers don't seem to work on my code (all looks correct). How do I create 'placeholder' and 'view only' values (JS is inputting longitude and latitude values in my code).

Thinking this is something to do with my 'fields' and 'labels' at the bottom. Placeholder value in the name field doesn't show (but form works fine). thanks!

```
class SafezoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Safezone
        name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput
                    (attrs={'id':'name', 'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Whynoplaceholdershows'}))
        useremail = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                    'id': 'useremail'}))
        latitudecentre = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.TextInput
                    (attrs={'id': 'latcentre1'}))
        longitudecentre = forms.FloatField(
                    widget=forms.TextInput
                    (attrs={'id': 'longcentre1'}))

        fields = ['useremail', 'name', 'longitudecentre', 'latitudecentre']
        labels = {
            "name": "Name of safezone",
            "useremail": "Alert Email",
            "latitudecentre": "Latitude",
            "longitudecentre": "Longitude",
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add additional properties to your form fields you need to do it above the Meta:

```
class SafezoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput
                (attrs={'id':'name', 'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Whynoplaceholdershows', 'disabled': True}))
    class Meta:
        model = Safezone
```

I presume that 'name' is model field - you should use 'placeholder' and 'disabled' for this purpose. Note that disabled is available since Django 1.9

Comment: smashed it thanks, simple as moving the meta class down thanks